# Padding trick aspect ratio element - Vertical centering

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

I'm trying to vertically center an element which uses padding-bottom to create the required aspect ratio (for a video). I want to have top and bottom black borders just like when a movie is displayed on a taller aspect ratio than it was filmed on:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
main{
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/1280) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:56.25%;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y4tcufo5/ - test case

I have tried the top:50% ; transform:translateY(-50%) ; tricks on the element, but nothing seems to be working! I know it's to do with using padding instead of width and height, but I cannot seem to rig the element to the design any other way.

Is it possible to solve this problem with either:

- Using the padding trick and another way of vertical centering the element
- Ditching the padding and achieving aspect ratio through another means
- Use flex box or something

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertically center anything with these four lines of code

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
max-height: 100%;
```

Apply this to a wrapper of the element that you want to vertically center

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4tcufo5/2/))

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <main></main>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
}
main{
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/1280) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:56.25%;
}
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed! I was so close!